# PowerMock Mockito: how to mock all static methods?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

Do we need to mock all static methods of a class when using PowerMock (with Mockito)? I mean, suppose we have:

```
class MockMe {
   public static MockMe getInstance(){
              //return new Instance via complex process;
   }

   public static List<X> anotherStaticMethod(){
      // does xyz
   }
}
```

My question, if I need to mock getInstance method, is it necessary to mock "anotherStaticMethod" as well?

PowerMock version:1.3, Mockito version:1.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can use partial mocking using [spy](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Partial_Mocking) in PowerMockito. Or you can use the stubbing API:

```
stub(method(MockMe.class, "getInstance")).toReturn(myMockMeInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking Static Method
How to mock and stub:

Add `@PrepareForTest` at class level.

```
@PrepareForTest(Static.class) // Static.class contains static methods
```

Call `PowerMockito.mockStatic()` to mock a static class (use PowerMockito.spy(class) to mock a specific method):

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
```

Just use `Mockito.when()` to setup your expectation:

```
Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(param)).thenReturn(value);
```